# BindableProperty Default value is not working correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am setting up a custom control and I've run into an odd issue where one, and only one, of my BindableProperty fields is not using the default value.  It's a float type and when stepping through the debugger, it's value is always 0.

Here I create the property and field.

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Stroke),
    typeof(float),
    typeof(ChartControl),
    1F,
    BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: RedrawAxisView);

public static readonly BindableProperty FontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(FontSize),
    typeof(float),
    typeof(ChartControl),
    12F,
    BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: RedrawAxisView);

public float Stroke
{
    get => (float)this.GetValue(StrokeProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
}

public float FontSize
{
    get => (float)this.GetValue(FontSizeProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value);
}
```

I'm implementing this in XAML using the following:

```xml
<xf:ChartControl x:Name="pChart">
    <xf:ChartControl.Stroke>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single" Android="3"/>
    </xf:ChartControl.Stroke>
    <xf:ChartControl.FontSize>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single" Android="36"/>
    </xf:ChartControl.FontSize>
</xf:ChartControl>
```

I later use both of these to create SkiaSharp paints, but I set a break point and I can see FontSize defaults to 0 on UWP where it should default to 12.  Stroke on the other hand defaults to 1, exactly as expected.  It does work if I do the following but this is not ideal as I would rather not set On Platform for UWP, I want it to use the defaults.

```xml
<xf:ChartControl.FontSize>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Single">
        <On Platform="UWP">12</On>
        <On Platform="Android">36</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</xf:ChartControl.FontSize>
```

Can anyone help me understand why I don't get a default value for FontSize?

Update: This is the PropertyChanged event if you need it.

```cs
private static void RedrawAxisView(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
{
    var bindableCanvas = bindable as ChartControl;
    bindableCanvas?.axisView.InvalidateSurface();  //SkiaSharp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to create custom control with BindableProperty,you said that you don't have the correct default for only one, please check if BindableProperty notify property changed firstly.

I see the property changed event is RedrawAxisView, so I guess that it may have some issue in this event.

```
 propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
            {
                var control = bindable as ChartControl;
                var changingFrom = oldValue as float;
                var changingTo = newValue as float;

               //do something with ChartControl
                //o is the old value of the property
                //n is the new value

            });
```

Here is the sample about create custom control with BindableProperty, you can take a look:

https://mindofai.github.io/Creating-Custom-Controls-with-Bindable-Properties-in-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: I'm not understanding your first sentence, but RedrawAxisView just invalidates the SkiaSharp canvas so it will will draw and run the events again.  This issue isn't affected by that.  Using the debugger the watch shows that the property never has a default value.  I am never assigning to this property except in XAML if the platform is Android.

Comment: @Tarazed According to your description, I can not reproduce your issue, so can you provide one sample at github,I will download your sample to test.

Comment: I can't upload the whole code set.  It's proprietary.

Comment: @Tarazed you just create simple sample that can reproduce your issue at github, I will download to test it.